# ASP.NET How to vertically center text in a LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I tried this, but text in LinkButton is still at top, not in vertical center (middle).

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle;">
<asp:LinkButton ID="REQUEST_TAB_LINKBUTTON" runat="server"  
    style="text-decoration:none"
    BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Large">&nbsp;Ask&nbsp;for&nbsp;help&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: As it is it just looks like a label with text. Is the problem the letter `p`?

Comment: Elaborate how you would like to view the text.